# Android: obtener canciones del dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para obtener las canciones del dispositivo pero no me sale ningún resultado, cuando sustituyo INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI por EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI si me salen resultados pero no son las canciones que he descargado

```
ArrayList<Canciones> canciones = new ArrayList<Canciones>();
    public ArrayList<Canciones> Obtener(Context context){
       ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor musicCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null
                );
       if(musicCursor!=null){
           while(musicCursor.moveToNext()){
            String artista=musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String titulo=musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            Long id=musicCursor.getLong(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

            canciones.add(new Canciones(id,titulo, artista));
        }
       }
      //  canciones.add(new Canciones(2, "sdfs", "dgr"));

       return  canciones;
    }
```